# Shorter words needed; can I say "observed caves"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> The caves that are used for observation

Can I just say "the observed caves"?

Answer (score 2):

"The observed caves" would imply that the caves themselves are being observed. Just "observation caves" would be fine, just like you have an [observation tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observation_tower).